# ¿Cómo codificar carateres extendidos en una api de ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, codificación, ascii

Mi backend es una api en ruby, que recibe los parámetros de peticiones, como el siguiente ejemplo:

Method:      PUT

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/zones

Body params: {"Zone_id": "22","name":"¡Ejemplo!"}

El problema es cuando se insertan caracteres de ascii extendido en mi caso el símbolo **¡**

Mi controlador recibe estos parámetros en la siguiente función:

```
# PUT /zones/1
def update
  if request.raw_post
    @type = "putzone"
    logger.info("Body params: #{request.raw_post}")
    @params = request.raw_post.force_encoding('UTF-8')
    create_event

    if response = get_notification
      render json: YAML.load(response)
      ReadCache.redis.del("notification-#{@type}-#{@params}-#{@device.id}")
    else
      logger.warn "ERROR: No response"
      render json: { "error" => "No response"}
    end
  else
    render json: { "error" => "Something went wrong, invalid parameters. Please try again with correct parameters"}
  end
end
```

Posteriormente, tengo que crear un Hash con estos parámetros (@params), y debo realizar la codificación a UTF-8 para posteriormente, guardarlo en caché como un JSON:

```
event = Hash.new
event = {
  :id => id,
  :params => @params,
  :retries => 2,
  :created_at => Time.now
}
logger.info("#{event}")
ReadCache.redis.set(id, event.to_json, ex: 30)
```

Cuando convierto el objeto event a JSON se reemplaza por un símbolo especial �. Además, por lo que he comprobado antes de hacerle la codificación en UTF-8, ya se cambia la codificación en alguna conversión previa y no sé como poder convertir ese caracter sin perder información de la codificación inicial.

He probado la codificación (ASCII => US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1) y otros, pero solo funciona con la codificación UTF-8 para poder realizar el parseo a JSON y como consecuencia, se pierde los caracteres especiales con esta codificación.

> ¿Cómo podría hacer la codificación sin perder el carácter espcial de
>   ascii extendido?

También he probado a forzar la codificación en el frontend (angularjs) con escape y decodeURIComponent, pero no resuelvo el problema, ya que la petición se realiza en la codificación correcta.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Hola Rafael. No hacia falta que hicieras esta publicacion. Podias haber editado la otra para traducirla. Borra pués [la otra publicacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109826/how-encoding-characters-extended-in-ruby-api). Y mira el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y como hacer preguntas de más calidad. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de la petición que está recibiendo el API?

Comment: Rafael, aqui no hay formas privadas de comunicacion. Toda la informacion relevante a la pregunta ha de estar en la pregunta (ni en los comentarios).

Comment: ¿El caracter se pierde cuando llamas el método `to_json` o cuando lo guardas en caché? Podrías verificarlo con `logger.info(event.to_json)`.

Comment: Ya funciona, gracias por tu ayuda. El problema no estaba en este punto. Sino en otro software, un servidor de sockets que al recoger este evento lo estaba codificando mal: event['params'].to_s.unpack("U*").map{|c|c.chr}.join